# Question about $E=mc^2$

Tags: special-relativity, energy, mass, mass-energy

When a nuclear reaction happens, the amount of mass disappeared satisfies $E=mc^2$. However, the reaction will stop at a certain point, there is no way to make the whole thing disappear into energy. So could it be only the slight amount of mass that reactable follows $E=mc^2$ but the rest of it doesn't?

Comment: $E=mc^2$ is generally incorrect. The correct formula "was first established by Paul Dirac in 1928 under the form $E=\sqrt{c^2p^2+(m_o c^2)^2} + V$, where V is the amount of potential energy." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation#Origins_and_derivation_of_the_equation

Answer (score 5):

No. When a particle and its anti-particle annihilate, 100% of their mass can be converted into another form of energy, such as massless photons. For all kinds of particles, the energy released in this process is always observed to be $mc^2$, no matter what the mass is.

If you want to second-guess Einstein, you’ll need to do it in some area of physics other than Special Relativity!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the reaction.

In nuclear reactions, only a part of the mass of the atoms involved turns into energy. For example, when a neutron hits a uranium-235 atom in a nuclear reactor, it can decay to a krypton-92 atom, a barium-141 atom, and 3 neutrons. The total mass of the starting particles are

$$1.008664\,amu\,\textrm{(1 neutron)} + 235.0439299\,amu\,\textrm{(1 $^{235}$U)} = 236.0525939\,\textrm{amu}$$

where *amu* is an atomic mass unit ($1/12$ the mass of a carbon-12 atom). The final mass of the product particles are

$$91.926156\,amu\,\textrm{(1 $^{92}$Kr)} + 140.914411\,amu\,\textrm{(1 $^{141}$Ba)} + 3(1.008664\,amu)\,\textrm{(3 neutrons)} = 235.866559\,amu$$

Most of the mass of the original neutron and uranium atom remain in the products. The missing mass ($0.1860349\,amu$) can be found in the kinetic energy of the 3 neutrons.

There are reactions that leave no mass behind. If you have an electron and a positron (the electron's antimatter counterpart), they can react to form two gamma ray photons. There will be no particles with mass afterwards, and the photons will have an energy equal to the total mass of the electron and posititron by way of $E=mc^2$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible if during the reaction a third particle intervenes.